# Write log file on successful checkout from success.phtml magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community

I want to write a custom log file which contains order and `timestamp` in the log file.

I tried `Mage::log()` but stops the file running afterwards and footer disappears.

Can anyone guide me in that?

Thank you

Comment: Could you post the code you tried to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to combine the timestamp and order in one single log call. This would cause an error. Mage::log() actually prepends the timestamp so all you would need to do is:

```
Mage::log($order->getData(), null, 'custom.log', true);
```

$order in the case above is an instance of the order class.

If doesn't work then its likely to be another error. I would turn on error logging and check your system.log and exception.log files.

You could also turn on error_reporting and developer mode in the index.php file and see what error is been thrown.

Comment: Can I add $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] to the log file?

Comment: You can do. You couldn't combine that with the array in 1 call to Mage::log though. They would have to be 2 separate calls.

Comment: I am adding Mage::log($order->getData(), null, 'custom.log', true);
Mage::log($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], null, 'custom.log', true); 

will this cause the script to die? Or will it continue everything to execute?

Comment: Colin I tried the above code and its breaking the success.phtml page as footer is not coming

Comment: Mage::log() will allow the script to execute. Can you post up the full template code here and also turn on error reporting and post up what error you are getting please. Mage::log() shouldn't break the code.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/bhargavmehta/2daa2d08505bf7c844b7

Comment: I was able to checkout and see the page fully rendered using that template in a child theme of RWD theme. See http://postimg.org/image/4plilk22d/ and http://postimg.org/image/o2331t3oh/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36914/discussion-between-colin-murphy-and-bhargav).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to write the entire order object which will make the script to die. Just write only the data you need. For example

```
Mage::log($order->getIncrementId(),null,'order.log');
```